# Azure Service Fabric - migrate/copy Stateful Actors info to another cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We are deploying a new Production Service Fabric Cluster in Azure to replace our existing one.  Most of our services are stateless, but we have a handful of them that are stateful and contain data mostly related to datetimes for triggering certain events.

Is it possible to export this data from the old and import to the new?